# How do I ensure AJAX still works after content moved from iFrame through DOM manipulation

Tags: ajax, iframe, dom-manipulation

After submitting an iFrame, content with AJAX enabled functions is returned and everything works.

Once I move the content out from the iFrame to the main page through DOM manipulation and remove the iFrame, AJAX stops working.

How can I make it work?

I grab the body content of the iFrame and move it to an outside element through .innerHTML

Comment: I know this was 10 years ago, but I'd appreciate it if you could accept my answer to the question, provided it satisfies the desired requirements? Gotta get that rep yo' 

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the AJAX implementation...

Once you've grabbed the DOM nodes from the iFrame and placed them in your < body >, they are essentially new DOM nodes.  Any events attached to them would need to be rebound and any code interacting with them would need to be re-executed.

Why not simply load the iFrame into the main page's DOM to begin with and execute the AJAX code there?